# C# ASP.NET Azure Mobile Services InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, azure

```
            try
            {
                JObject jO = new JObject();
                // Change 'MobileService' to the name of your MobileServiceClient instance.
                // Sign-in using Facebook authentication.
                user = await client.LoginAsync(provider, jO);
                Session["userId"] = user.UserId;
                Session["authToken"] = user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                // error
            }
```

I'm getting error saying I must specify the access token.

```
The POST Facebook login request must specify the access token in the body of the request.
```

Does it mean I need to add the Facebook SDK into my project and have to get the access token via the SDK and add it into the JObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to use the Facebook SDK to get the access_token then add it to your JObject using the following:

```
jO.Add("access_token", JsonValue.CreateStringValue(accessToken));
```

I think this post has what you're looking for.

[Authenticating with Facebook for Mobile Services in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991869/authenticating-with-facebook-for-mobile-services-in-azure)